# sum values only if they are different

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm trying to make a report with Visual Studio 2013.
My Data comes from a SQL Query and the generated table looks like:

---

```
    data11  |data12  | 127 
    data21  |data22  | 127 
    data31  |data32  | 413
    data41  |data42  | 413
    data51  |data52  | 287
    data61  |data62  | 287
    data71  |data72  | 287
    data81  |data82  | 287
    ...
```

---

My question is, how can i realize a sum of the last Values, but only count them once if they are the same. For the example the sum should be 827. 
I'm quite new to both SQL and the Reporting System via Visual Studio and I hope you guys can help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL supports `sum(distinct)`.  I have never used it.  It usually indicates an issue with the underlying data -- namely that it is not normalized.  It runs a big risk of calculating the wrong value, if two items "happen" to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(x.nameOfYourColumn) FROM (SELECT * FROM yourTable GROUP BY nameOfYourColumn) as x
```

put in **nameOfYourColumn** the name of column that holds the value (your 3rd data) and put in **yourTable** the name of your table.